# Add application to Privacy > Accessibility unchecked?

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility

I want to add my application to the list of apps that can control the computer in *Preferences > Privacy > Accessibility*.

I know that you cannot enable Accessibility programmatically, but I've seen several applications add themselves to the list unchecked. How can I replicate this?